# Weak linking on iPhone refuses to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, weak-linking

I've got an iPhone app that's mainly targetting 3.0, but which takes advantage of newer APIs when they're available. Code goes something like this:

```
if (UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != NULL) {
    [nc
        addObserver: self
        selector:    @selector(irrelevantCallbackName:)
        name:        UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
        object:      nil];
}
```

Now, according to everything Apple's ever said, if the relevant APIs are weakly linked, that will work fine because the dynamic linker will evaluate `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` to `NULL`. Except that it doesn't. The application compiles, but as soon as it hits `if (UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != NULL)` it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Is this simply a matter of a compiler flag I need to set? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I *knew* I would find the answer by merely searching for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification on SO… It must be the most common reason for developers to need to deal with conditionally available globals.

Comment: @Pierre Lebeaupin: That seems to be the case.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Aaand I figured it out. For symbols that are not functions (`extern const int foobar`, for instance), you have to compare against the address of the symbol, not the symbol itself, so:

```
if (&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification != NULL)
    etc;
```

Which in retrospect is kind of obvious, but I still fault the entire universe around me for not ever mentioning the distinction.

Comment: If you are using LLVM, you have to do some tricks to get it to not optomize out your if statement. This works for me.

BOOL backgroundOK = &UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != NULL;
if (backgroundOK) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification bject:nil];
}

Comment: Using vanilla GCC, but if LLVM is looking at it differently, I suspect it may be a bug on Apple's part (as Apple explicitly tells developers to do this sort of runtime check with weak-linked symbols.) You might want to write up a test case and submit it to Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com . :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I had to do when checking for an external framework constant.

```
const CLLocationAccuracy * ptr = &kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
BOOL frameworkSupports = (ptr != NULL);
if (frameworkSupports) {
    return kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
} else {
    return kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}
```

It would not work without the ptr variable.