# iPhone, check for existence of constant

Tags: iphone, extern

How can you check if a constant is set at runtime? For instance, in iOS 4, UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification is available, but when running on iOS 3 it will through an error if you try to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should probably look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002833/weak-linking-on-iphone-refuses-to-work), which in my opinion also answers yours. `if (&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification != NULL)` should be dynamic-linking-safe and tell you whether the constant exists or not.

Comment: If you are using LLVM, you have to do some tricks to get it to not optomize out your if statement. This works for me.

BOOL backgroundOK = &UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != NULL;
if (backgroundOK) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification bject:nil];
}

Comment: Has this optimizer bug been already fixed in LLVM/Clang compiler? In which version?

Comment: It's not a bug in LLVM, but a feature. LLVM will optimize out statements with no side-effect and it is good. But it makes stuff a bit tougher for this type of code.

Comment: Why not using `#ifdef`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei because UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification is not a macro...