# how to check if CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid is available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'd like to use the CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid - check, which is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

how can i prevent this from being called on a iOS 3 device (it wil crash...)?

i tried with:

```
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid != NULL) {
  //use the check
} else {
  //do a own check
}
```

why do iOS3 devices try to "use the check" instead of "do a own check"?
how would one call the CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid properly - and only if it's available on the current iOS running?

Comment: Have you tried implicit os version check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weak linking on iPhone refuses to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002833/weak-linking-on-iphone-refuses-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right for the dynamic loader. I asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002833/weak-linking-on-iphone-refuses-to-work).