# Runtime API availability check (weak linking) -- incorrect behavior on 10.5

Tags: macos, api, compatibility, weak-linking

I'm building my application on 10.6 but targeting 10.5 for deployment.  I want to take advantage of the Service Management SMJobBless api when the program will run on 10.6, but I obviously will still need to use a privileged installer tool when running on 10.5.

I weakly link to the Service Management framework in my executable target.  I have tried several variations of the code:

```
if (SMJobBless != NULL) ...

if (SMJobBless) ...

bool const /* or non-const */ useBlessAPI = SMJobBless != NULL;
if (useBlessAPI) ...
```

And I've even tried using the [compiler flags listed in a similar-seeming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274753/how-to-make-weak-linking-work-with-gcc/730267#730267).

On 10.6, `printf("%p %d", SMJobBless, SMJobBless != NULL)` (correctly) prints a non-null pointer value for SMJobBless and 1 for non-null.

When I copy the app bundle to 10.5, the `printf` tells me that SMJobBless is 0x0, but (incorrectly) prints 1 for a non-null pointer.

The only way I've gotten it to work is by *turning off all optimizations* and assigning the function pointer to a variable.

```
Boolean (* const blessAPI) (CFStringRef, CFStringRef, AuthorizationRef, CFErrorRef *) = &SMJobBless;
```

But I can't turn off optimization for production code!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weak linking on iPhone refuses to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002833/weak-linking-on-iphone-refuses-to-work)

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan I re-read [your answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002833/weak-linking-on-iphone-refuses-to-work/3002845#3002845) and re-tried taking the address of the function I want, but as I said in the Q, that only works if I set compiler optimization to None.

Comment: And you tried with the ampersand? Which compiler are you using, GCC or LLVM?

Comment: I tried all 3 compilers: gcc, llvm, and llvm-gcc.  That method finally worked (with compiler optimization on) when I made the function pointer `volatile` as noted in my answer below.

Comment: @Richard, please do not roll back edits that clean up burninated tags.  [availability] was removed for a reason.

Comment: @Charles You're saying that the tag no longer exists on SO?  That should have been mentioned in the edit notes. Also, please provide an alternative.

Comment: @Richard There is no alternative, it was a [horrible little meta tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195902/135887).  The tag edit interface doesn't have a space to explain why tags are edited.

Comment: @Charles There's a separate interface for editing only tags?  The interface I see for editing (tags and content) includes a line to describe the changes.

Comment: @Richard Correct.  It's [unlocked at 2,000 reputation points with the rest of the no-peer-review-needed edit privs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found that, [similar to the question/answer cited in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002833/weak-linking-on-iphone-refuses-to-work/3002845#3002845), if I assigned the function pointer to a `volatile` variable, then everything evaluated ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `extern Boolean SMJobBless() __attribute__((weak_import));` in your files that use the function. It might not be getting marked as weak properly.